# Linux CentOS-7 give a certain user acces to only a certain file path

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, user-management, terminal

I would like to give a created user a new home directory and have him only be able to access that certain home directory, however, the directory the user is supposed to access has already been created and has a bunch of subdirectories. I know that it might be possible if I restrict everything but the directory that the user is supposed to access it might work but I thought there might be an easier way.

If this question has been asked before or been explained somewhere else I couldn't find it.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

In short, what you are trying is not possible unless you use a `chroot` environment or any kind of containers to seperate the user environment from your host.

If you restrict the access of the user to only his home directory, the user wouldn't be able to login as it wouldn't be possible to execute any command or create files in */tmp* which applications rely on to be writeable.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be with something like `docker-cmd`, that builds a encapsulated jail for each user.

**See:** https://github.com/clevcode/docker-cmd

You can certainly do something with SELinux and namespaces but that would be substantially more work involved.